# Can't change app's background on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am having problems to change the background of an app. I have developed this second app using my first app as base, so I basically replaced the background image of app1 for app2's on drawables, with the exact same size, type and name..

The problem: when I run app2 everything works perfectly, but the background loaded is form app1.

Am I missing something? I have done some research and already tried cleaning project, and wipe user data on emulator, but nothing..

Comment: also have changed the package names?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: Try to clean Your second project and delete it from Your device. Then install it again and try....

Comment: There are drawables for multiple screen densities in multiple folders (`drawable-*dpi`). Did you replace them all?

Comment: Also a bit of code could make us see the solution faster... paste ur xml file and class

Comment: Okay, I will paste the codes as soon as I can.. and yes I have replaced all drawables from multiple screens.. I have also deleted and installed, and cleaned and nothing worked..Thanks for your support and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

you need to clear your files in drawble folder in this location;
..\eclipse\workspaces\YourProjectName\bin\res\crunch\drawable

clear all files there, good luck!